# Diff-in-Diff with 1 treated group with A, 1 treated group with A+B and 1 control group, : can I identify without multicolinearity?

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity, difference-in-difference

Friends,
thank you for your help, I'll try to be concise:

I want to perform a Diff in Diff with three groups of US states: a control group, a group treated with policy P1, and a group treated with policy P1 AND P2 (both).
The basic model in my head:
$y_{s,t} = \alpha + \mu_{1}Post_{s} + \gamma_{1}P1_{t} +  \gamma_{2}P2_{t} + \gamma{3}(P1*P2)_{t} + \delta_{1}(Post*P1)_{s,t} + \delta_{2}(Post*P2)_{s,t} + \delta_{3}(Post*P1*P2)_{s,t}$

But the issue is that
$\gamma_{3}(P1*P2)_{s}$ is perfectly colinear with $\gamma_{1}P1_{s}$ and $\gamma_{2}P2_{s}$
and
$\delta_{3}(P1*P2*Post)_{s,t}$  is perfectly colinear with $\delta_{1}(P1*Post)_{s,t})$ et $\delta_{2}(P2*Post)_{s,t}$.

Can I recover the isolated effect of P2 (i.e. $\delta_{2}$) by dropping collinear terms? Do I need an additivity assumption for the effect of the two policies? Can I say that $\delta_{2} = \delta_{3} - \delta_{1}$? (Let's assume that the treatments are simultaneous. No TWFE required).

Thank you very much for your insights.

Cheers.